# Assignment from incompatible pointer type when using Linked Lists

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I'm attempting to use a simple linked list example, in attempt to understand the basic idea behind using them, for later use. However, I've gotten confused about how to set each node in the list to a certain value. I.e here, I want to set member "a" to the address of "b" and member "b" to the address of c. However, this is where the warning occurs,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct List
{
    int data;
    struct List * next;
};

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{

    struct List * a = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    a->data = 0;
    a->next = NULL;

    struct List * b = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    b->data = 1;
    b->next = NULL;

    struct List * c = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    c->data = 2;
    c->next = NULL;

    a->next = &b; //warning occurs here
    b->next = &c;
}
```

Is there a way to set the values of a->next (a.next) and b->next(b.next) without any warning whatsoever?

Comment: You want `a->next` to point to *the space allocated by malloc to which `b` is pointing*.  Not to *the pointer `b`*.

Comment: So the first one and last one (malloc calls) are fine then? just the * b one?

Comment: All the malloc calls are fine, the problems are the two lines giving you the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a->next` is of type `struct List *`.

`b` is of type `struct List *`.

`&b` is of type `struct List **`.

You probably meant to do this: `a->next = b;`

Answer (score 0):

`b` is already a pointer to a `struct List` so you don't need the `&` operator.

Just do:

```
a->next = b;
```